# How to Sort a List of Tuples based on the item order of another List

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list: `l = ['orange', 'banana', 'apple', 'pear']`

I also have a list of tuples, and within each tuple the first item matches the values from prior list: `list_tuples = [('pear',value),('apple',value),('orange',value),('banana',value)]`

Is there any way to re-order the tuples in `list_tuples` based on the ordering of list `l`? So that the expected output of `list_tuples` would be `[('orange',value),('banana',value),('apple',value),('pear',value)]`?

Comment: try the function `sorted` that gets list + function + revers  or the function `list.sort()`

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom [key-function](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) for `sorted` which consider the index (position) in the list:

```
>>> l = ["orange", "banana", "apple", "pear"]
>>> list_tuples = [("pear","value"),("apple","value"),("orange","value"),("banana","value")]
>>> sorted(list_tuples, key=lambda x: l.index(x[0]))
[('orange', 'value'), ('banana', 'value'), ('apple', 'value'), ('pear', 'value')]
```

Comment: This unnecessarily costs *O(n ^ 2 x log n)* in time complexity.

Comment: @blhsing OP didn't ask for an efficient solution. Why don't you suggest a better, more efficient one?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for loop. But I would recommend using .sort function for a performance reasons. It also makes your code look clean.

Anyways, here is a code that does what you want.
I used a custom key to access the element's index on the first list and then use that to sort the second list. Just be aware that this only works if there are no duplicates on the first list. if there are, then you should use a for loop.

```
first_list = ['orange', 'banana', 'apple', 'pear']

value = 0 # value doesn't matter here.

def custom_sort(element):
    return first_list.index(element[0])

second_list = [('pear',value),('apple',value),('orange',value),('banana',value)]

second_list.sort(key=custom_sort)

print(second_list)
```

Comment: Looks like the answer published by @Sven but without `lambda` ...

Comment: It is. just this is easier to understand for people that are not comfortable with lambda. His answer is cleaner though. If I was writing it for myself I would have written it with lambda.